# RKHunter and CHKRootkit Hunter

Tags: linux, centos, web-server, cron, centos6

Is it possible for them to only send an email if something is found? I've never had them find something but the emails get annoying when they come in every day and you have to check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for "--report-warnings-only" in the options for rkhunter.

From `man rkhunter`,

```
--rwo, --report-warnings-only
This option causes only warning messages to be displayed. 
This can be useful when rkhunter is run via cron. Other
options may be used to force other items of information
to be displayed.
```

I suggest you use `man` to find out what options CHKRootkit Hunter has (at a guess, looking at the man page, `-q` might be enough, although the debian cron script does some post processing).

You will need to find out where they are being executed on your server and see which options are being passed.